# Convert Cloudflare API response to yaml

Tags: bash, jq

When I retrieve all records for a hosted zone in [Cloudflare](https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-list-dns-records), e.g. of [response](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.97f9bb6785be4e799fb2a7560919f07f), I need to create from it the following yaml structure:

```
name_zones: # this line we create 
  .zone_name: # the value is taken from the response
    auth_key: XXX # this line we create 
    records: # this line we create
# iterate over all records
      - name: .name
        type: .type
        priority: .priority # create line if value set|exist
        content: .content
        ttl: .ttl # create line if value set|exist
```

e.g. `jq` code which almost done this:
`jq '.result[] | {name: .name, type: .type, content: .content, ttl: .ttl} + if has("priority") then {priority} else null end' | jq -n '.name_zone.zone_name.auth_key.records |= [inputs]' | yq r -P -`

How to pass or create the value of `zone_name` and `auth_key: XXX`?

Comment: Please, share an MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: YAML is a *superset* of JSON. If the YAML is otherwise valid JSON, you can use `jq`, but what you show isn't.

Comment: It might be *possible* to generate YAML as raw text using `jq`, but it certainly is not the appropriate tool for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your two invocations of jq can be replaced by just one, as shown in the answer below.

Second, there are currently (at least) two `yq`s in the wild:

- python-based yq (https://kislyuk.github.io/yq) - hereafter `python-yq`
- go-based yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)

For better and/or worse, version 4 of the go-based yq is significantly different from earlier versions, so if you want to use the current go-based version you may have to make adjustments accordingly. To simplify things (at least from my point of view), I will replace your `yq r -P -` by:

```
python-jq -y .
```

The following produces the output shown below.

```
< cf_response.json \
  jq '{name_zones:
        {zone_name: .result[0].zone_name,
         auth_key: "XXX",
          records:
            [.result[]
             | {name, type, content, ttl}
               + if has("priority") 
                 then {priority} 
                 else null end] }} '|
  python-yq -y .
```

#### Output

```
name_zones:
  zone_name: test.com
  auth_key: XXX
  records:
    - name: test.com
      type: A
      content: 111.111.111.111
      ttl: 1
    - name: test.com
      type: TXT
      content: google-site-verification=content
      ttl: 1
    - name: test.com
      type: MX
      content: smtp.test.com
      ttl: 1
      priority: 0
```

### auth_key

If you want to pass in the value of `auth_key` as a parameter to jq, you could use the command-line sequence `--arg auth_key XXX`, and then use `$auth_key` in the jq program.